# Is the absolute max/min and the local max/min an $x$ or $y$ value?

Tags: derivatives

For example, when we say that $f(c)$ is an absolute maximum value. Are we saying that the $y$ value obtained at the $x$ value $c$ is the absolute max? 
And therefore, can we say that $c$ is the $x$ value where the absolute max is obtained?

In brief: are absolute/local max/min $y$ values?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. You distinguish absolute maximums and minimums concern the entire range of y values. Local maximums and minimums concern whether the y is the greatest or smallest as $x$ approaches $c$ from the left and the right.